# Istanbul coverage with built React JavaScript and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, jasmine, istanbul

I have a built version of a React module that I'm testing successfully with Jasmine but when I try to use Istanbul to determine my tests coverage it shows that I'm only testing the Require.js Define lines of the code.

In particular the render function is clearly being called in my test (as I have tests that are passing on a div that must be being rendered) but is showing as not being covered in Istanbul.

Any ideas why this might be?

N.B. I am not testing the JSX files only their built JS versions.